# OpenStreetMap Direct Routing Request via GET error

Tags: openstreetmap

I have problem with OpenRouteService API (Direct Routing Request via GET described in here http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService#Direct_Routing_Request_.28via_GET.29).

My request is:

http://openls.geog.uni-heidelberg.de/route?start=18.609%2C53.02&end=18.749%2C53.49&via=18.01%2C53.12&lang=pl&distunit=KM&routepref=Pedestrian&&weighting=Recommended&avoidAreas&useTMC=false&noMotorways=false&noTollways=false&noUnpavedroads=false&noSteps=false&noFerries=false&instructions=false

(from Toruń in Poland to Grudziądz via Bydgoszcz).

Unfortonatly, I get error:

"validation error: Expected element 'EndPoint@http://www.opengis.net/xls' instead of 'viaPoint@http://www.opengis.net/xls' here in element WayPointList@http://www.opengis.net/xls"

If I put antyhing in "via=" this error appear.

When I change "via=" to empty value:

http://openls.geog.uni-heidelberg.de/route?start=18.609%2C53.02&end=18.749%2C53.49&via=&lang=pl&distunit=KM&routepref=Pedestrian&&weighting=Recommended&avoidAreas&useTMC=false&noMotorways=false&noTollways=false&noUnpavedroads=false&noSteps=false&noFerries=false&instructions=false
all works fine.

Is it problem with my request or api isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the frontend API of OpenRouteService receives the GET requests correctly, but after it builds the request in xml and relays it to the backend server the server fails to validate the request correctly. It should be a problem with the backend server.

The frontend php code is [here](https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice/blob/2695485ffea534b7d3fba7e49b7799fe38be23ba/php/GETRoute.php)  for reference.

The web frontend, which POSTs the xml directly to another backend server, seems to work correctly with via points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there's actually nothing we can do about that?

Comment: Send a bug report to the service.  Use the POST interface if you want to use the service, or consider alternatives such as OSRM.

Comment: There are lots of alternatives, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers

Comment: @headuck you were right, there's an error in GET service, I rewrite my code and now I'm sending POST request and it's working ok.